# How to add contact related list of chosen lookup Account in following code

Tags: visualforce

I want to add contacts related to the Account which I will choose using Lookup.Kindly help me out how to navigate with it.

**Visualforce page**:

```
      <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ExtensionController5">
      <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Account Information" id="account">
      <apex:pageBlocksection>
       <apex:inputField value="{!con.accountId}"/>
       <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!accountselected}" rerender="account,msgs" status="stat"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

**Controller**:

```
       public class ExtensionController5{
      private ApexPages.StandardController Stdctrl;
      public ExtensionController5(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
      Stdctrl=controller;
      }
      public void AccountSelected()
      {
      contact con=(contact) StdCtrl.getRecord();   
      if (!string.IsBlank(con.accountid))
      {
     con.account=[select Name,Phone from Account where id=:con.accountid];
     }
      else
     {
     con.account=null;
     }
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is that `con` needs to be publicly accessible to the VF page but you have it declared as a method variable:

```
public void AccountSelected()
  {
  contact con=(contact) StdCtrl.getRecord();  // This is a variable scoped inside a method
  ...
```

to fix this, declare `con` outside of any method

```
public Contact con {get; set;}
```

and change your code fragment to initialize to:

```
public void AccountSelected()
  {
  this.con=(Contact) StdCtrl.getRecord();
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you cropredy for such a quick reply.I am new to visualforce and it was taking my whole day! My next requirement is ,I want to get all the contacts related to Account on my VF page when I select Account using lookup. Could you please tell me how do I navigate it? Hope I was clear with my question.

Comment: Please ask this as a different question showing the work you've done.

Comment: Hello @cropredy ,yes I have created another question for the same. Here is the link.Hope I am clear with my question,but if it isnt kindly let me know. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358356/not-able-to-fetch-contact-related-list-for-the-account-using-extension-control