# Not able to fetch contact related list for the Account : Using Extension controller

Tags: visualforce

I want to fetch contacts related to the Account,Account which I will choose using Lookup(Please see scrrenshot).Kindly help me out how to navigate with it and where I am going wrong.

**VF Page**

```
  <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ExtensionController6">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Information" id="account">
        <apex:pageBlocksection>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.accountId}" />
            <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!accountselected}" rerender="account,msgs"
                status="stat" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!ShowContact}" value="Show Contact" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<apex:relatedList subject="{!ac.id}" list="contacts" />
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class ExtensionController6{

    public ExtensionController6(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }

    private ApexPages.StandardController Stdctrl;
    public Contact con {get; set;}
    public Account ac {get;set;}
    
    public ExtensionController6(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        Stdctrl=controller;
    }
    
    public void AccountSelected() {
        this.con=(Contact) StdCtrl.getRecord();
        this.ac=(Account) StdCtrl.getRecord();  
        if (!string.IsBlank(con.accountid)) {
            con.account=[select Name,Phone from Account where id=:con.accountid];
        } else {
            con.account=null;
        }
    }
    
    public pagereference ShowContacts() {
        ac = [select id from Account where id=:con.accountid];
        system.debug('AC==========='+ac);
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello,so I have a requirement that all Contacts should be displayed related to  the Account,Account which I will choose with lookup (screenshot). I am using extension controller here.Is it right method?